# Application doesn't enter the loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have that code :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$wynik = 0;
$licznik = 0;
wykonaj();

function wykonaj()
{
echo '1';
for($i = 1; $i == 404; $i++)
{
$temp = $i / 100;
echo $temp;

if(is_int($temp*1.5))
{
global $wynik, $licznik;
$wynik++;
//$liczba[$licznik] = $i + ($i/100)*1.5;
$licznik++;
}

}
}

echo "Ilosc wynikow : $wynik<br/>Liczby sa nastepujace :";


?>
```

My application returns :

> 1Ilosc wynikow : 0 
>   Liczby sa nastepujace :

So I think there is an error (logical ?), because that line - `echo $temp;` isn't displayed yet, but 1 before a loop is displayed. I tried a lot of things, but I could not find any solution. Why are my errors ? Compiler doesn't tell anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only enter the loop if `$i` is equal to `404`, which it's set to `1` right off so that won't happen.

Syntax in a `for` loop is something like:

```
for([Set Vars]; [Set Conditional]; [Set Increment])
```

The loop only runs when the conditional is true.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Mising <= in the for condition

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$wynik = 0;
$licznik = 0;
wykonaj();

function wykonaj()
{
    echo '1';
    for($i = 1; $i <= 404; $i++)
    {
        $temp = $i / 100;
        echo $temp;

        if(is_int($temp*1.5))
        {
            global $wynik, $licznik;
            $wynik++;
            //$liczba[$licznik] = $i + ($i/100)*1.5;
            $licznik++;
        }
    }
}

echo "Ilosc wynikow : $wynik<br/>Liczby sa nastepujace :";

?>
```

[demo here](http://codepad.org/Zw8pS1Hh)